# Convert Date and Time to other Date and Time with PHP

Tags: php, datetime

I am getting date in format `2019-11-26T16:30:00+01:00` from an API and want to convert it to a format like `Di. 26. Nov. 2019 / 16:30`.

I am usinig following code, but always get 1 hour difference: `Di. 26. Nov. 2019 / 15:30 Uhr`.

If I use `2019-11-26T16:30:00+02:00` - I get `Di. 26. Nov. 2019 / 14:30 Uhr` (2 hours earlier).

Here is my php code:

```
$timstp = strtotime('2019-11-26T16:30:00+1:00');
echo date('d.m.Y H:i:s', $timstp);
```

How can I get correct date?

Comment: Double check your php timezone, maybe thats the issue

Comment: I set timezone to - and now it seems correct hour

Answer (score 1):

Use the DateTime class. The format method returns the result in English.

```
$input = '2019-11-26T16:30:00+1:00';
$date = date_create($input)->format('D. d. M. Y /H:i \U\h\r');
echo $date;  //Tue. 26. Nov. 2019 /16:30 Uhr
```

For an output in other languages ​​like German I recommend the DateTime extension class [dt](https://github.com/jspit-de/dt).

```
$input = '2019-11-26T16:30:00+1:00';
$date = dt::create($input)->formatL('D d. M Y / H:i \U\h\r','de_DE');
echo $date; //Di. 26. Nov. 2019 / 16:30 Uhr
```

**Update:**

Does the API get entries from different time zones? If so, is the question what is needed?
The local time of the time zone or a unique time base for comparability?
The examples above show the local time of the time zone.
To create a uniquet basis, the DateTime object can be converted to a different time zone how UTC.

```
$input = '2019-11-26T15:30:00+5:00';
$date = date_create($input)
  ->setTimeZone(new DateTimeZone('UTC'))
  ->format('D. d. M. Y / H:i:s')
;
echo $date;  //Tue. 26. Nov. 2019 / 10:30:00
```

Comment: Thanks! But why is date_create($input)->format('D. d. M. Y /H:i \U\h\r'); another time than strtotime() does?

Comment: Your input contains the time zone +1: 00. DateTime handles this time zone correctly. strtotime returns a time stamp (UTC) and date converts this into local time (+ 2h Germany summer time). Hence the 1 hour difference.

Comment: + 2h Germany summer time is nonsense for November. I think you have to set the correct timezone with date_default_timezone_set () so that date works properly.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$datetime = new DateTime('2019-11-26T16:30:00+1:00');
echo $datetime->format('d.m.Y H:i:s');
```

find more details about DateTime [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.settimezone.php)

Comment: "Try this" does not make for a good answer. You should explain *how* and *why* this solves their problem. I recommend reading, "[How do I write a good answer?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)